# jquery submit search query and display typed text

Tags: jquery

blank I have a form setup like so:

```
<form id="search">
    <input id="searchbox" type="text" size="40" placeholder="your search.." />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#searchbox').keypress(function (e)
{
   e.preventDefault();
   if (e.which == 13) 
     {
        hitParse();
     }
});

function hitParse(){

    // here parse api posts query to parse.com servers
}
```

Now if I type anything in the `#searchbox` the typed text is not displayed because of `e.preventDefault()` i guess but when i press enter it executes `hitParse()` fine n sends blank query n all that. But if i remove preventDefault() then it displays typed text fine but the hitParse() doesn't execute. How can I achieve both: display typed text and access that text and when pressed enter hitParse() with actual typed query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `preventDefault` into the if statement

```
$('#searchbox').keypress(function (e)
{

   if (e.which == 13) 
     {
        e.preventDefault();
        hitParse();
     }
});

function hitParse(){

    // here parse api posts query to parse.com servers
}
```